# Join Multiple Tables in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have four tables named table1, table2, table3, and table4.
I want to select the quantity from all tables as per item.
There is only the same field named item in all tables. I use join to join all tables but in output, one record is displayed so many times.

Here is my code:

```
WITH 
    issue AS(SELECT item_code,qty,stock_entry_type FROM `tabStock Entry Detail` where stock_entry_type='Material Issue')
select @item:=i.item_code, 
@opening:=sed.qty,
@purchase:=pri.qty,
@issue:=issue.qty,
@bin:= ifnull(bin.actual_qty)
from issue,`tabItem` i
 join `tabStock Entry Detail` sed on i.item_code=sed.item_code
 join `tabPurchase Receipt Item` pri on sed.item_code=pri.item_code
 join `tabBin` bin on pri.item_code=bin.item_code 
where sed.stock_entry_type='Material Receipt'
```

[This is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu3Sk.png)

I want to display the record only one time.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: what is the join criteria between `issue` and `tabItem i`?  Avoid the `,` join. It make seeing this mistake hard.

Comment: Without issue, there is the same error. I use the issue only for the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Your:

```
from issue,`tabItem` i
```

is equivalent to

```
from issue
cross join tabItem i
```

It will produce one row for each combination of issue and tabItem rows.  (So each issue row will be repeated as many times as there are rows in tabItem.)

It sounds like you want to be doing:

```
from issue
join tabItem i on i.item_code=issue.item_code
...rest of your joins
```

Comment: I also used cross join but all records are displayed multiple times.

Comment: Right, you don't *want* to do cross join, but you implicitly were